# InfoWindow doesn't want to close with Google Maps Api V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i can't close the info window of the marker i'm dragging, any idea ?
Thanks for your help

```
function mapClick(event) {

        createLocationMarker(event.latLng);

}
function createLocationMarker(location) {
    var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location)
    var gMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:location, map:gMap2, draggable: true});

    gMap2.setCenter(location);
    displayMarkerPosition(gMarker);

     google.maps.event.addListener(gMarker, "dragstart", closeMapInfoWindow );
     google.maps.event.addListener(gMarker, "dragend", function() { displayMarkerPosition(gMarker); });
}

function closeMapInfoWindow() {infowindow.close(); }

function displayMarkerPosition(gMarker) {
    var message = "my message";
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
    {   content : message,
    });

    infowindow.open(gMap2,gMarker); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you define `infowindow` in a private scope, but access it outside that scope. Add this to the beginning of your script:

```
var infowindow;
```

And remove 'var ' from your constructor line:

```
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
```

The finished code (from your sample) would [look like this](http://pastie.org/773066).

**A little more background**

When you define a variable with `var`, it is tied to that scope. If you define it in a function, only that function and other functions defined in it can access the variable. The only other way to pass it around is as a parameter in a function.

**Update** I would do this to facilitate multiple infowindows. Notice I have reverted to the original `var` declaration to keep it scoped to that function. I then return the reference to the object to use it later:

```
function mapClick(event) {
    createLocationMarker(event.latLng);
}
function createLocationMarker(location) {
    var clickedLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location)
    var gMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position:location, map:gMap2, draggable: true});

    gMap2.setCenter(location);
    // Store reference to info window
    var info = displayMarkerPosition(gMarker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(gMarker, "dragstart", function(){ info.close } );
    google.maps.event.addListener(gMarker, "dragend", function() { displayMarkerPosition(gMarker); });
}

function displayMarkerPosition(gMarker) {
    var message = "my message";
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
      {   content : message }
    );

    infowindow.open(gMap2,gMarker); 
    return infowindow; // Return the reference to the infowindow
}
```

Comment: Rapide, clair et précis ! Merci beaucoup Doug :)

Comment: @Shipow Avec plaisir <-- I sure hope that means "my pleasure", if not you can laugh since I speak only english!

Comment: "The only other way to pass it around is as a parameter in a function."
I wish to have more than one marker, so there is multiple infowindow defined, where should I use parameter to access instance ?
thx for your time

Comment: @Shipow I updated my answer to handle what you were asking. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: It's working !! thx again you saved my night :)
info.close() <---

Comment: actually info.close should be OK if you remove function(){} around it